# How to monitor bandwidth usage for the month at interface with my Mikrotik AB493ah running RouterOS 4.17?

Tags: network-monitoring, dsl

Since at&t recently announced monthly bandwidth caps, I figured I would try to setup something to monitor my monthly bandwidth. Preferably I would like to monitor at the pppoe interface, or possibly my dhcp server interface. I haven't found a way to do this. I already have queues setup for all the devices in house with sticky statics. I would use the queue to monitor the bandwidth, but they seem wrong sometimes, and I am going through a wireless AP so I dunno how much overhead that adds. So, what I am looking for is a way to measure inbound and outbound traffic on 1 interface of my router for a period of time. Thanks!

edit: all systems behind the router are either windows or devices like iPod, blu-ray player, etc. I do have access to an Ubuntu Linux vps so I could set something up in Linux if it could be done remotely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use "MikroTik Traffic Counter" http://www.mikrotik.com/archive.php

It is windows application, that use traffic accounting. Get curent statistic from microtic by http and collect it and agregate by months.

2. use passthru action in microtic firewall to count traffic incrementally. And script sheduled to start of month for saving values to file and reset counters.
3. Use netflow to collect traffic data. But i dont know tool to agregate netflow by months.